# 作成済のviewflipperのイメージを変更したい。

Tags: android

以下のようにfor文で`ViewFlipper`にviewを追加した後に、ある特定のページの`ImageView`を
変更したいと考えてます。

例えば25ページ分のviewを持つ`ViewFlipper`があって、2ページ目の`ImageView`を変更したいとします。

ググったところ`getChildAt`に1と指定することで、2ページ目のviewが取得できそうですが、そのviewに対して`ImageView`の画像の更新を行う方法が分かりません。

教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
private ViewFlipper viewflipper;
private View fl;


    for (int i=0; i < itemList.size(); i++){
       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    　　LinearLayout oViewFliperChildLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview,null);
       TextView textView = (TextView)oViewFliperChildLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_Text);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)oViewFliperChildLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_View);
       String s = getResources().getString(itemList.get(i));
       textView.setText(s);

    myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resM, itemList.get(i));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myImage);
     viewflipper.addView(oViewFliperChildLayout);
     }

        viewflipper.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                fl = viewflipper.getChildAt(1);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

解決しましたので、自己レスです。
postではなく以下のようにすることで作成済のviewflipperを差し替えできました。

```
private ViewFlipper viewflipper;
private View fl;


    for (int i=0; i < itemList.size(); i++){
       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    　　LinearLayout oViewFliperChildLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview,null);
       TextView textView = (TextView)oViewFliperChildLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_Text);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)oViewFliperChildLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_View);
       String s = getResources().getString(itemList.get(i));
       textView.setText(s);

    myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resM, itemList.get(i));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myImage);
     viewflipper.addView(oViewFliperChildLayout);
     }

    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)viewflipper.getChildAt(3);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.getChildAt(0);
    ImageView im = (ImageView)v.getChildAt(1);
    String s = getResources().getString(itemList.get(1));
    tv.setText(s);

    myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resM, itemList.get(1));
    im.setImageDrawable(null);
    im.setImageBitmap(null);
    im.setImageBitmap(myImage);

    viewflipper.removeViewAt(3);
    viewflipper.addView(v, 3);
```

Comment: `ImageView im = (ImageView)v.getChildAt(1);`はおそらく`ImageView im = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_View);`とした方が意図が伝わりやすいです。`ViewFlipper`はシンプルですが、全てのページの画像を読み込んでしまうので、メモリを有効に扱える`ViewPager`が便利です。